# Regarding output message of launch-prefix="time"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was running 2 nodes using launch file in which I include `launch-prefix="time"`. The following is the obtained output message:

```
2.58user 2.89system 2:01.48elapsed 4%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 307200maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+664215minor)pagefaults 0swaps
0.77user 0.23system 2:01.95elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 221712maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+14178minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I have several questions regarding this which are listed as follow:

1. How do I interpret the output of it after `killing` all the running processes. Is it `elapsed` means time taken for that node and CPU means it used certain percent of it?
2. How do I know that which output message is corresponding to which node? Were they ordered in ascending or descending order, I mean the output message with respect to nodes placed in launch file?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28479/regarding-output-message-of-launch-prefix=%22time%22/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a `--format=` option to your `time` prefix, with a `printf()`-style formatting string.

See "`man time`" for the details.

EDIT:

Launch the nodes with different prefix arguments, like this (untested):

```
launch-prefix = "/usr/bin/time --format='node1: %E sec, %P'"
launch-prefix = "/usr/bin/time --format='node2: %E sec, %P'"
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-27**:
Could you give me an example of line that I can determine which node belongs to in order to differentiate them,  printf()-style that u meant. How do I append that?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-27**:
Thanks a lot, that works! I only edit the above as the following (launch-prefix = "time --format='node1: %E sec, %P'"), no difference I guess, feature-wise..